# How to use scipy.optimize with pymc3 random variables?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pymc3

For my pymc3 model, I need to calculate the value E which is given as M = E - e*sinE 
Here M and e are pymc3 random variables. I want to use scipy.optimize to find E from the given expression but I get the error that "Should be real value, not TensorVariable". How can use TensorVariables to calculate another random variable?

```
@np.vectorize
def compute_E(M, e):
    """Solve Kepler's eqns for eccentric anomaly given mean anomaly"""
    f = lambda E, M=M, e=e: E - e * np.sin(E) - M
    return optimize.brentq(f, 0, 2 * np.pi)

with one_planet_model:
    V = pm.Uniform('V',lower=-2000,upper=2000)
    e = pm.Uniform('e',lower=0,upper=1)
    pomega = pm.Uniform('pomega',lower=0,upper=2*np.pi)
    chi = pm.Uniform('chi',lower=0,upper=1)
    T = pm.DensityDist('T',lambda value: - np.log(value) - np.log(np.log(15000 * 5)))
    K = pm.DensityDist('K',lambda value: -np.log(value+1)-np.log(2001))
    s = pm.DensityDist('s',lambda value: -np.log(value+1)-np.log(2001))
    sd = np.sqrt(err1**2 + s**2)
    M = 2 * np.pi * ((jd / T + chi) % 1)
    E = compute_E(M,e)
    f = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(1 + e) * np.sin(E / 2),
               np.sqrt(1 - e) * np.cos(E / 2))
    mu = V - K * (np.sin(f + pomega) + e * np.sin(pomega))
    rv_obs = pm.Normal('rv_obs',mu=mu,sd=sd,observed=rv1)
```

Comment: you can try `.eval()` to cast a theano tensor to numpy